# Error Compiling ACSIL code in SierraChart - SimpleMovAvg function

Tags: c++, sierrachart

I am very new to ACSIL coding and I am struggling converting my already existing code from previous platform to SierraChart, really hoping someone will be able to help.

The logic I am trying to replicate is really simple:

1. **First**: 3 Inputs (Length, CalcLength,SmoothLength) they will all host integer numbers
2. **Second**: Variables: (MA, Main, Signal)
3. **Third**: I am looping from ss= 0 to Length -1:   if the close of the current index > the open of the current index then ss += 1   if
   the close of the current index < the open of the current index then
   ss -= 1
4. **Finally:**

   - MA = SimpleMovAvg(ss, Length)
   - Main = SimpleMovAvg(MA, SmoothLength)
   - Signal = SimpleMovAvg(MA, CalcLength)

My understanding from the error of the compiler below is that the MA, Main and Signal need to be handled as array but I am really struggling to know how to solve it.

Here is the full code:

```
// The top of every source code file must include this line
#include "sierrachart.h"

// For reference, refer to this page:
// https://www.sierrachart.com/index.php?page=doc/AdvancedCustomStudyInterfaceAndLanguage.php

// This line is required. Change the text within the quote
// marks to what you want to name your group of custom studies. 
SCDLLName("TrueMomentum_H")

//This is the basic framework of a study function. Change the name 'TemplateFunction' to what you require.
SCSFExport scsf_TrueMomentum_H(SCStudyInterfaceRef sc)
{
    SCSubgraphRef Subgraph_Ma = sc.Subgraph[0];
    SCSubgraphRef Subgraph_Main = sc.Subgraph[1];
    SCSubgraphRef Subgraph_Signal = sc.Subgraph[2];
    SCSubgraphRef Subgraph_ZeroLine = sc.Subgraph[3];
    SCSubgraphRef Subgraph_UpperLine = sc.Subgraph[4];
    SCSubgraphRef Subgraph_LowerLine = sc.Subgraph[5];
    SCSubgraphRef Subgraph_Overbought = sc.Subgraph[6];
    SCSubgraphRef Subgraph_Oversold = sc.Subgraph[7];

    SCInputRef Input_Length = sc.Input[0];
    SCInputRef Input_CalcLength = sc.Input[1];
    SCInputRef Input_SmoothLength = sc.Input[2];

    if (sc.SetDefaults)
    {
        sc.GraphName = "MyMomentum";

        sc.GraphRegion = 0;
        sc.ValueFormat = 2;
        sc.AutoLoop = 1;

        Subgraph_Main.Name = "Ma";
        Subgraph_Main.DrawStyle = DRAWSTYLE_LINE;
        Subgraph_Main.PrimaryColor = RGB(0, 255, 0);
        Subgraph_Main.SecondaryColor = RGB(255, 0, 0);
        Subgraph_Main.SecondaryColorUsed = true;
        Subgraph_Main.DrawZeros = false;
        
        Subgraph_Main.Name = "Main";
        Subgraph_Main.DrawStyle = DRAWSTYLE_LINE;
        Subgraph_Main.PrimaryColor = RGB(0, 255, 0);
        Subgraph_Main.SecondaryColor = RGB(255, 0, 0);
        Subgraph_Main.SecondaryColorUsed = true;
        Subgraph_Main.DrawZeros = false;

        Subgraph_Signal.Name = "Signal";
        Subgraph_Signal.DrawStyle = DRAWSTYLE_LINE;
        Subgraph_Signal.PrimaryColor = RGB(0, 255, 0);
        Subgraph_Signal.SecondaryColor = RGB(255, 0, 0);
        Subgraph_Signal.SecondaryColorUsed = true;
        Subgraph_Signal.DrawZeros = false;

        Subgraph_ZeroLine.Name = "ZeroLine";
        Subgraph_ZeroLine.DrawStyle = DRAWSTYLE_LINE;
        Subgraph_ZeroLine.PrimaryColor = RGB(169, 169, 169);
        Subgraph_ZeroLine.DrawZeros = true;

        Subgraph_UpperLine.Name = "UpperLine";
        Subgraph_UpperLine.DrawStyle = DRAWSTYLE_LINE;
        Subgraph_UpperLine.PrimaryColor = RGB(255, 0, 0);
        Subgraph_UpperLine.DrawZeros = false;

        Subgraph_LowerLine.Name = "LowerLine";
        Subgraph_LowerLine.DrawStyle = DRAWSTYLE_LINE;
        Subgraph_LowerLine.PrimaryColor = RGB(0, 255, 0);
        Subgraph_LowerLine.DrawZeros = false;

        Subgraph_Overbought.Name = "Overbought";
        Subgraph_Overbought.DrawStyle = DRAWSTYLE_LINE;
        Subgraph_Overbought.PrimaryColor = RGB(255, 0, 0);
        Subgraph_Overbought.DrawZeros = false;

        Subgraph_Oversold.Name = "Oversold";
        Subgraph_Oversold.DrawStyle = DRAWSTYLE_LINE;
        Subgraph_Oversold.PrimaryColor = RGB(0, 255, 0);
        Subgraph_Oversold.DrawZeros = false;

        Input_Length.Name = "Length";
        Input_Length.SetInt(14);
        Input_Length.SetIntLimits(1, MAX_STUDY_LENGTH);

        Input_CalcLength.Name = "Calculation Length";
        Input_CalcLength.SetInt(5);
        Input_CalcLength.SetIntLimits(1, MAX_STUDY_LENGTH);

        Input_SmoothLength.Name = "Smooth Length";
        Input_SmoothLength.SetInt(3);
        Input_SmoothLength.SetIntLimits(1, MAX_STUDY_LENGTH);

        return;
    }

    int len = Input_Length.GetInt();
    SCFloatArrayRef s = sc.Subgraph[7]; // Create an array to store 's' values
    SCFloatArrayRef MA = sc.Subgraph[8]; // Create an array to store 'MA' values
    SCFloatArrayRef Main = sc.Subgraph[9]; // Create an array to store 'Main' values
    SCFloatArrayRef Signal = sc.Subgraph[10]; // Create an array to store 'Signal' values

    s[sc.Index] = 0;
    for (int ss = 0; ss < len; ss++)
    {
        if (sc.Close[sc.Index] > sc.Open[sc.Index - ss])
            s[sc.Index] = s[sc.Index] + 1;
        else if (sc.Close[sc.Index] < sc.Open[sc.Index - ss])
            s[sc.Index] = s[sc.Index] - 1;
        //else
        //  s[sc.Index] = 0;
    }

    //MA[sc.Index] = sc.SimpleMovAvg(s, Input_CalcLength.GetInt());
    //Main[sc.Index] = sc.SimpleMovAvg(MA, Input_SmoothLength.GetInt());
    //Signal[sc.Index] = sc.SimpleMovAvg(Main, Input_SmoothLength.GetInt());


    MA[sc.Index] = sc.SimpleMovAvg(s[sc.Index],Subgraph_Ma, Input_CalcLength.GetInt());
    Main[sc.Index] = sc.SimpleMovAvg(MA[sc.Index], Subgraph_Main,Input_SmoothLength.GetInt());
    Signal[sc.Index] = sc.SimpleMovAvg(Main[sc.Index],Subgraph_Signal ,Input_SmoothLength.GetInt());


    Subgraph_Main[sc.Index] = Main[sc.Index];
    Subgraph_Signal[sc.Index] = Signal[sc.Index];
    Subgraph_ZeroLine[sc.Index] = 0;
    Subgraph_UpperLine[sc.Index] = len;
    Subgraph_LowerLine[sc.Index] = -len;
    Subgraph_Overbought[sc.Index] = len * 0.8;
    Subgraph_Oversold[sc.Index] = -len * 0.8;
}
```

And Here is the error I am getting from the compiler:

```
-- Starting remote build of Custom Studies Source files: TrueMomentum_H.cpp. 64-bit --     02:11:35

Allow time for the server to compile the files and build the DLL.

The remote build did not succeed. Result:

TrueMomentum_H.cpp: In function 'void scsf_TrueMomentum_H(SCStudyInterfaceRef)':
TrueMomentum_H.cpp:118:93: error: no matching function for call to 's_sc::SimpleMovAvg(float&, float&, int)'
  118 |  MA[sc.Index] = sc.SimpleMovAvg(s[sc.Index],Subgraph_Ma[sc.Index], Input_CalcLength.GetInt());
      |                                                                                             ^
In file included from TrueMomentum_H.cpp:2:
sierrachart.h:1253:18: note: candidate: 'c_ArrayWrapper<float>& s_sc::SimpleMovAvg(SCFloatArrayRef, SCFloatArrayRef, int, int)'
 1253 |  SCFloatArrayRef SimpleMovAvg(SCFloatArrayRef In, SCFloatArrayRef Out, int Index, int Length)
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
sierrachart.h:1253:18: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 3 provided
sierrachart.h:1257:18: note: candidate: 'c_ArrayWrapper<float>& s_sc::SimpleMovAvg(SCFloatArrayRef, SCFloatArrayRef, int)'
 1257 |  SCFloatArrayRef SimpleMovAvg(SCFloatArrayRef In, SCFloatArrayRef Out, int Length)
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
sierrachart.h:1257:47: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'float' to 'SCFloatArrayRef' {aka 'c_ArrayWrapper<float>&'}
 1257 |  SCFloatArrayRef SimpleMovAvg(SCFloatArrayRef In, SCFloatArrayRef Out, int Length)
      |                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
TrueMomentum_H.cpp:119:100: error: no matching function for call to 's_sc::SimpleMovAvg(float&, float&, int)'
  119 |  Main[sc.Index] = sc.SimpleMovAvg(MA[sc.Index], Subgraph_Main[sc.Index],Input_SmoothLength.GetInt());
      |                                                                                                    ^
In file included from TrueMomentum_H.cpp:2:
sierrachart.h:1253:18: note: candidate: 'c_ArrayWrapper<float>& s_sc::SimpleMovAvg(SCFloatArrayRef, SCFloatArrayRef, int, int)'
 1253 |  SCFloatArrayRef SimpleMovAvg(SCFloatArrayRef In, SCFloatArrayRef Out, int Index, int Length)
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
sierrachart.h:1253:18: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 3 provided
sierrachart.h:1257:18: note: candidate: 'c_ArrayWrapper<float>& s_sc::SimpleMovAvg(SCFloatArrayRef, SCFloatArrayRef, int)'
 1257 |  SCFloatArrayRef SimpleMovAvg(SCFloatArrayRef In, SCFloatArrayRef Out, int Length)
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
sierrachart.h:1257:47: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'float' to 'SCFloatArrayRef' {aka 'c_ArrayWrapper<float>&'}
 1257 |  SCFloatArrayRef SimpleMovAvg(SCFloatArrayRef In, SCFloatArrayRef Out, int Length)
      |                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
TrueMomentum_H.cpp:120:106: error: no matching function for call to 's_sc::SimpleMovAvg(float&, float&, int)'
  120 |  Signal[sc.Index] = sc.SimpleMovAvg(Main[sc.Index],Subgraph_Signal[sc.Index] ,Input_SmoothLength.GetInt());
      |                                                                                                          ^
In file included from TrueMomentum_H.cpp:2:
sierrachart.h:1253:18: note: candidate: 'c_ArrayWrapper<float>& s_sc::SimpleMovAvg(SCFloatArrayRef, SCFloatArrayRef, int, int)'
 1253 |  SCFloatArrayRef SimpleMovAvg(SCFloatArrayRef In, SCFloatArrayRef Out, int Index, int Length)
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
sierrachart.h:1253:18: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 3 provided
sierrachart.h:1257:18: note: candidate: 'c_ArrayWrapper<float>& s_sc::SimpleMovAvg(SCFloatArrayRef, SCFloatArrayRef, int)'
 1257 |  SCFloatArrayRef SimpleMovAvg(SCFloatArrayRef In, SCFloatArrayRef Out, int Length)
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
sierrachart.h:1257:47: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'float' to 'SCFloatArrayRef' {aka 'c_ArrayWrapper<float>&'}
 1257 |  SCFloatArrayRef SimpleMovAvg(SCFloatArrayRef In, SCFloatArrayRef Out, int Length)
      |                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~

-- End of Build --     02:11:40
```

Answer (score -1):

Yo

```
 #include "sierrachart.h"

SCDLLName("TrueMomentum_H")

SCSFExport scsf_TrueMomentum_H(SCStudyInterfaceRef sc)
{
SCSubgraphRef Subgraph_Ma = sc.Subgraph[0];
SCSubgraphRef Subgraph_Main = sc.Subgraph[1];
SCSubgraphRef Subgraph_Signal = sc.Subgraph[2];
SCSubgraphRef Subgraph_ZeroLine = sc.Subgraph[3];
SCSubgraphRef Subgraph_UpperLine = sc.Subgraph[4];
SCSubgraphRef Subgraph_LowerLine = sc.Subgraph[5];
SCSubgraphRef Subgraph_Overbought = sc.Subgraph[6];
SCSubgraphRef Subgraph_Oversold = sc.Subgraph[7];

SCInputRef Input_Length = sc.Input[0];
SCInputRef Input_CalcLength = sc.Input[1];
SCInputRef Input_SmoothLength = sc.Input[2];

if (sc.SetDefaults)
{
    sc.GraphName = "MyMomentum";

    sc.GraphRegion = 0;
    sc.ValueFormat = 2;
    sc.AutoLoop = 1;

    Subgraph_Ma.Name = "Ma";
    Subgraph_Ma.DrawStyle = DRAWSTYLE_LINE;
    Subgraph_Ma.PrimaryColor = RGB(0, 255, 0);
    Subgraph_Ma.SecondaryColor = RGB(255, 0, 0);
    Subgraph_Ma.SecondaryColorUsed = true;
    Subgraph_Ma.DrawZeros = false;

    Subgraph_Main.Name = "Main";
    Subgraph_Main.DrawStyle = DRAWSTYLE_LINE;
    Subgraph_Main.PrimaryColor = RGB(0, 255, 0);
    Subgraph_Main.SecondaryColor = RGB(255, 0, 0);
    Subgraph_Main.SecondaryColorUsed = true;
    Subgraph_Main.DrawZeros = false;

    Subgraph_Signal.Name = "Signal";
    Subgraph_Signal.DrawStyle = DRAWSTYLE_LINE;
    Subgraph_Signal.PrimaryColor = RGB(0, 255, 0);
    Subgraph_Signal.SecondaryColor = RGB(255, 0, 0);
    Subgraph_Signal.SecondaryColorUsed = true;
    Subgraph_Signal.DrawZeros = false;

    Subgraph_ZeroLine.Name = "ZeroLine";
    Subgraph_ZeroLine.DrawStyle = DRAWSTYLE_LINE;
    Subgraph_ZeroLine.PrimaryColor = RGB(169, 169, 169);
    Subgraph_ZeroLine.DrawZeros = true;

    Subgraph_UpperLine.Name = "UpperLine";
    Subgraph_UpperLine.DrawStyle = DRAWSTYLE_LINE;
    Subgraph_UpperLine.PrimaryColor = RGB(255, 0, 0);
    Subgraph_UpperLine.DrawZeros = false;

    Subgraph_LowerLine.Name = "LowerLine";
    Subgraph_LowerLine.DrawStyle = DRAWSTYLE_LINE;
    Subgraph_LowerLine.PrimaryColor = RGB(0, 255, 0);
    Subgraph_LowerLine.DrawZeros = false;

    Subgraph_Overbought.Name = "Overbought";
    Subgraph_Overbought.DrawStyle = DRAWSTYLE_LINE;
    Subgraph_Overbought.PrimaryColor = RGB(255, 0, 0);
    Subgraph_Overbought.DrawZeros = false;

    Subgraph_Oversold.Name = "Oversold";
    Subgraph_Oversold.DrawStyle = DRAWSTYLE_LINE;
    Subgraph_Oversold.PrimaryColor = RGB(0, 255, 0);
    Subgraph_Oversold.DrawZeros = false;

    Input_Length.Name = "Length";
    Input_Length.SetInt(14);
    Input_Length.SetIntLimits(1, MAX_STUDY_LENGTH);

    Input_CalcLength.Name = "Calculation Length";
    Input_CalcLength.SetInt(5);
    Input_CalcLength.SetIntLimits(1, MAX_STUDY_LENGTH);

    Input_SmoothLength.Name = "Smooth Length";
    Input_SmoothLength.SetInt(3);
    Input_SmoothLength.SetIntLimits(1, MAX_STUDY_LENGTH);

    return;
}

sc.DataStartIndex = Input_Length.GetInt() - 1;

SCFloatArrayRef s = sc.Subgraph[7].Arrays[0]; // Using Arrays[0] of Subgraph[7] to store 's' values

// Calculate 's' values
s[sc.Index] = 0;
for (int ss = 0; ss < Input_Length.GetInt(); ss++)
{
    if (sc.Index - ss < 0) break;

    if (sc.Close[sc.Index] > sc.Open[sc.Index - ss])
        s[sc.Index] = s[sc.Index] + 1;
    else if (sc.Close[sc.Index] < sc.Open[sc.Index - ss])
        s[sc.Index] = s[sc.Index] - 1;
}

// Calculate Moving Averages
sc.SimpleMovAvg(s, Subgraph_Ma, sc.Index, Input_CalcLength.GetInt());
sc.SimpleMovAvg(Subgraph_Ma, Subgraph_Main, sc.Index, Input_SmoothLength.GetInt());
sc.SimpleMovAvg(Subgraph_Main, Subgraph_Signal, sc.Index, Input_SmoothLength.GetInt());

Subgraph_ZeroLine[sc.Index] = 0;
Subgraph_UpperLine[sc.Index] = Input_Length.GetInt();
Subgraph_LowerLine[sc.Index] = -Input_Length.GetInt();
Subgraph_Overbought[sc.Index] = Input_Length.GetInt() * 0.8;
Subgraph_Oversold[sc.Index] = -Input_Length.GetInt() * 0.8;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).